# Continuous and Properly discontinuous group action implies quotient space is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I think that a continuous and properly discontinuous (there is always a neighborhood $U$ around $x$ such that $g\cdot U\cap U$ nonempty only if $g=1$) group action $G$ on $M$ has $M/G$ Hausdorff.

How can I approach this? I'm beginning to think this may not be true but can't find a counterexample.

Comment: You may write the definitions you are working with.

Comment: @M.U. I apologize for being unclear. I have explained the terms.

Comment: Is $G$ assumed to be discrete? Are there any assumptions on $M$?

Comment: The statement you are trying to prove is false even for smooth cyclic group actions on surfaces. You need to change the notion of proper discontinuity to the more standard one (in terms of compact sets).